# About the statement $g_1 \sim g_2 \iff Hg_1=Hg_2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have a question about my notes of algebraic structures.

> Let $G$ be a group. Let $H \leq G$. We define that
>   \begin{equation}
> g_1 \sim g_2 \iff g_1g_2^{-1} \in H.
> \end{equation}

My professor said that $g_1 \sim g_2 \iff Hg_1=Hg_2$, and I don't see why.

\begin{equation}
g_1 \sim g_2 \iff g_1g_2^{-1} \in H \iff \exists\ h \in H \mid g_1g_2^{-1}=h \iff g_1=hg_2 \implies Hg_1=Hg_2.
\end{equation}

But then it will be $g_1 \sim g_2 \implies Hg_1=Hg_2$, not $g_1 \sim g_2 \iff Hg_1=Hg_2$.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also have that $Hg_1=Hg_2\Rightarrow$ $\exists h_1, h_2$ such that $h_{1}g_{1}=h_{2}g_{2}$ which gives $g_{1}g_{2}^{-1}=h_{1}^{-1}h_{2}\in H$ and hence $g_{1}\sim g_{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $g_1 \sim g_2$. Then by definition $g_1g_2^{-1} \in H$. Now let $g \in Hg_1$. Then $g=hg_1$ for some $h \in H$. But $Hg_1=Hg_2$, so $hg_1=h'g_2$ for some $h' \in H$. Then $g_1 = h^{-1}h'g_2 \in Hg_2$. Thus we have shown that $Hg_1 \subseteq Hg_2$. The other direction is similar.

On the other hand, suppose $Hg_1 = Hg_2$. Then $hg_1=h'g_2$ for some $h,h' \in H$. But then $g_1g_2^{-1} = h' h^{-1} \in H$.

Comment: OP had already done the first part (and with one variable less).